# Why nuxt.config.js build.babel is ignored on app start, but work on app update?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, babeljs

My `nuxt.config.js` file has the following section

```
  build: {
    babel: {
      presets (_, [_1, _2]) {
        return [['@babel/preset-env', {}]]
      },
      plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
          {
            regenerator: true
          }]
      ]
    }
  }
```

If I start my app (`yarn dev`), this section is ignored, and I've got `regeneratorRuntime is not defined` error instead of backend answer when I call my REST API (server middleware). But if after that (while server is up and running) I perform some changes in nuxt.config.js (i.e. set `regenerator` to false and then again to true), app is beeing regenerated and my REST API starts working fine.

`yarn generate` fails with `ERROR  ServerMiddleware Error: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

How to make it working always?